# Solve Fokker Plank PDE using numerical methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am aiming to solve the Fokker Plank PDE
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (f(x)p)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2(g(x)p)}{\partial x^2}=0.
\end{equation}
Using the finite difference method, we can discretize the equation and the problem is transformed into a tri-diagonal linear system of equations and can be solved fast.

My question is how can I make sure the solution from the linear system is consistent with the definition of $p$, i.e., positive and sum up to one. Maybe setting a proper boundary condition?

Comment: The second requirement can be enforced via $$ \sum_i p_i = 1$$ which fixes essentially one of the boundary points. This condition is often applied in the context of second order PDEs with periodic boundary conditions to fix the second boundary node by prescribing a certain average.

The first condition, $p_i > 0$ should be guaranteed by the stability properties of the numerical scheme: For a well-posed problem you are for sufficiently small $\Delta t, \Delta x$ arbitrarily close to the true solution which should rule out negative point values.

Comment: But after adding this requirement, how can you still solve the problem efficiently, say, with linear complexity?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to get the fixed boundary point?

Comment: Linear complexity in what? Solving a linear system requires in general $N^3$, if you use an iterative scheme you might be faster, but there are still $N^2$ operations such as vector-matrix multiplications involved.